# How to read Bluetooth input stream from Xbox one controller on Mac

Tags: macos, bluetooth, xbox-one

I’m trying to view the input stream my Xbox one controller send my MacBook to create some custom shortcuts, but I can’t find any clear directions online, or the instructions are way too technical for me. I am willing to learn, but I don’t know what to dive into specifically, or what resources I need. I am familiar with c/c++, js and a some shell, and I have Xcode and atom. Thank you so much, and sorry for the format. The mobile app is not super format-friendly.

Comment: When you say "the instructions are way too technical for me," which instructions are you reading? This question will likely be closed as "too broad," but we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @RobNapier What I mean is the other answers that I have read on Stack Overflow that I though might answer my question seemed to start in the middle of the process, or didn’t make sense and was over my head.

Comment: I'd start here: https://github.com/quantus/xbox-one-controller-protocol This isn't a published protocol; you're going to be doing a lot of reverse engineering of your own. For writing software for the Mac to connect to the Xbox, see the Core Bluetooth programming guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257). macos also has a lower-level IOBluetooth available, but you probably won't need that. Core Bluetooth should be enough to do what you want.

Comment: @RobNapier awesome! This is exactly why I was looking for to get me started! Thank you so much!